# Understanding the structure, '又什么...' and '又没什么...'

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

**From what I know** (correction would be appreciated), '又什么...' is often used in rhetorical questions, for example:

- 又什么麻烦 : what's troublesome about... (it's not troublesome)
- 又什么不满意 : What's there to feel unsatisfied about (there's nothing to feel unsatisfied about)

Then what about  '又没什么...'?

Does the '没' word make it have the opposite meaning?

Comment: It's supposed to be 有什麽麻煩、有什麽不滿意. 有什麽麻煩 (literally *have what trouble?*) means *what's so troublesome about...*, same idea for the second phrase. 又沒什麽 is different (it uses 又, not 有); it means something like *there's nothing (to make a big deal out of) here*.

Comment: @droooze what is 沒? Is that a typo or something else?

Comment: Oh, I looked it up. It looks like a variant form of 没.

Comment: 又 often disappears in translation, 
又什么：iciba：What? 我又什么都感觉不到了.又什么公交车可以到达? 什么又能够吸引你呢? 我又能做什么 What could I do 这又算什么 what you call this 我又算什么 What am I bkrs：你们又在争什么呢？
What are you arguing about this time?

Answer (score 3):

又什么麻烦/ is a wrong expression. The correct one is **有**什么麻烦, which could be either a rhetorical or a generic question. The normal expression is 又有什么... and in some cases  有 can be omitted, but you should be careful. In your example, 又有什么不满意 and 又有什么麻烦， 有 should not be omitted.

Well, in 又没(有)什么麻烦, 又 is more like the English word **anyway** in my opinion. So, 又没(有)什么麻烦 could be interpreted as *there isn't any trouble, anyways.*

Compare 又没有什么麻烦 and 又有什么麻烦. The latter is a rhetorical device as you said. The former is a normal negative sentence.  Both denote the same underlying meaning, but with a bit different tones, which are the same as the correspondent English sentences.

An interesting phrase I also want to add here is *又什么事*，which is short for 又有什么事. In this context, 有 can be omitted. So, I suggest you add 有 all the time unless you know for sure it's right to drop it in your context.

Comment: I've seen neither 又没有什么麻烦 nor 又没什么麻烦 being used, only 又有什么麻烦, which would suggest one's a bit annoyed like "problems again?". Are you sure you've not made an error?

Comment: @Zuoanqh 又没(有)什么麻烦 is a normal negative sentence.

Comment: yeah actually you're right, i wasnt thinking it like that. thanks.

Comment: cf。＂汉语８００虚词用法词典＂， **又** 七、用在返回句或否定句里；加强语气。used in a rhetorical question or a negative sentence for emphasis (1)我这又不是出租车，顺路捎你一段，怎么能收钱呢？（２）这又不是做买卖，哪能那么斤斤计较？（３）我们又不是初次见面，你那么客气干什么？（４）你又不是来玩儿的，怎么老不去上课？（５）我又不是小孩子，难道连这个道理都不知道？（６）他又不是说你，你生什么气呀？（７）我又没动你的电脑，你看我干什么？（８）我又没惹你，你冲我发什么脾气呀？（９）我又不是你，我哪知道你心里是怎么想的！（１０）你又不是中国人，哪有什么身份证，你拿护照就行了！

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, it's most likely a mistype (misconversion by IME) of "有什么麻烦" and "有什么不满意". When used in proper context and tone, they can be meant to be rhetorical questions, otherwise, they are merely questions.

If you believe this is not a mistype, specifying **which dialect** (or where in China you seen these being used) we're talking about would be greatly helpful. I am born and raised in Beijing, in case you're wondering whether I'm capable to make such a judgment.